# Problem with inequality proof with metrics.

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

In the unbounded metric space $(S,d)$, we fix $a\in S$, and define $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{d(a,x)},  &x\ne a \\ 1, &x=a. \end{cases}$$

I need to prove that $f(x)-f(y)\leq d(x,y) \leq f(x)+f(y) $.

Is this provable ?

The right-hand-side of the inequality seems more true than the left.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you defining $f$ if $f$ doesn't appear in the inequalities at all?

Comment: I edited so that it can be more clear.

Comment: This is even less clear. Are you trying to prove the inequalities, or the entire equivalence?

Comment: How is this less clear? I need to prove the first inequalities with the f's

Comment: My point exactly. You claim in comments that you need to prove the first inequalities. But the way your question is written, i.e. "I need to prove $A\iff B$", it seems as though you want to prove the **equivalence** $A\iff B$ (which is trivially true), not the inequalities themselves. Anyway, the inequalities are false, as my answer shows.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the standard metric over $\mathbb R$, for any $a$, we can fix $x=a+0.01$ and $y=a-1$ to get

$$\frac{1}{d(x,a)} - \frac{1}{d(a,y)} = 100 - 1 = 99$$

while $d(x,y) = 1.01$.